# The diagram shows the arc $ABC$ of a circle with radius $8$cm. The lines $AD$ and $CD$ are tangents. Calculate the area of the region shaded yellow

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The diagram shows the arc $ABC$ of a circle with centre $O$ and radius $8$cm.

The lines $AD$ and $CD$ are tangents to the circle.

The $\angle AOC = \frac 23\pi$ radians.

[image]

Calculate the area of the region (shaded yellow in the diagram) enclosed by $AD$, $CD$ and the arc $ABC$ giving your answer to three significant figures.

I tried to find the answer but it is showing up as incorrect.

In my attempt to answer the question:

Split vertically to form two identical triangles $OAD$ and $OCD$.

$$\angle DOC = \frac \pi 3$$
$$\tan \angle DOC = \tan \frac \pi 3 = \frac{DC}{8}$$
$$DC = 8 \tan \frac \pi 3 = 8 \sqrt{3} = AD$$
Area of $\triangle OCD = \frac 12 \times DC \times OC = \frac 12 \times 8 \times 8 \sqrt{3} = 32 \sqrt{3}$

Area of $\lozenge AOCD = 2 \times $ Area of $\triangle OCD = 64 \sqrt{3} = 110.85... = 111 \,(3sf) \,cm^2$

Not sure where to go from here. Would be very grateful for advice. Thanks.

Comment: $S = \bar{AD}\cdot\bar{AO}-\frac{\pi}{3}\bar{AO}^2$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks. Corrected now.

Comment: Were you able to finish the problem after reading my answer or user1017615's answer?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes. I subtracted the area of the sector from kite AOCD. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

With your edit, you have correctly calculated the area of the kite $AOCD$.  To complete the problem, you have to subtract the area of the sector bounded by the radii $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OC}$ and arc $ABC$ from the area of kite $AOCD$.  The area of a sector with central angle of radian measure $\theta$ in a circle with radius $r$ is
$$A_{\text{sector}} = \frac{\theta}{2\pi} \cdot \pi r^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach :

Area of yellow region = Area of △ADC - Area of segment ABC

Area of segment ABC = Area of sector OABC - Area of △AOC

Hope this helps !